# Looking for an elementary argument for calculation of $(-1)^{\frac{\phi(p^k)}{2}}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I got by an queer calculation that for $p$ odd prime these formulas are valid with $\phi(n)$ being the Euler $\phi$-function $$(-1)^{\frac{\phi(p^k)}{2}}=1 \qquad\hbox{if $p\equiv 1\mod 4$} 
$$ and $$(-1)^{\frac{\phi(p^k)}{2}}=-1 \qquad\hbox{if $p\equiv 3\mod 4$} 
$$ What is/are the usual argument(s) to prove this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember the formula for prime powers: $\phi(p^k) = (p - 1)p^{k - 1}$. For example, $\phi(3^4) = 2 \times 3^3 = 54$.

If $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, then $\phi(p^k) \equiv 0 \bmod 4$, so $\frac{\phi(p^k)}{2}$ is guaranteed to be even.

But if $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$, then $p - 1 \equiv 2 \bmod 4$, a relation that will be maintained when you multiply by any odd number, such as powers of an odd prime. Therefore $\frac{\phi(p^k)}{2} \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, odd.

Answer (score 0):

The second half of your statement is wrong, unless $k=1$.

The proof of the first half is easy: For $p \equiv 1 \mod 4$,  $\phi(p^k)=(\phi(p)^k = (p-1)^k \equiv 0 \mod 4$ so the exponent you have is half of a multiple of 4, thus is even.

Comment: i think Alonso proved it correctly.

Comment: I think Mark ought to try `Table[EulerPhi[3^n]/2, {n, 25}]` in Mathematica or Wolfram|Alpha and rethink his answer.